# Custom rewrite after the default term link URL

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a taxonomy `car` and a couple terms like `kia`, `honda`, and `toyota`.

Using the function `get_term_link()`, I can get a term archive link like this:

```
site.com/car/honda/
```

I am trying to use custom rewrite rules to get this structure:

```
site.com/car/honda/{$trim}
```

My rewrite rule looks like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    home_url() . '/car/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?taxonomy=car&term=$matches[1]&model=$matches[1]&trim=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

However it does not work properly. The default term archive links work (`site.com/car/honda`), but if I add anything as a `$trim`, WordPress redirects to a 404 which leads me to believe that my regex isn't being matched at all.

My taxonomy is non-hierarchical.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Revised answer)*

### So Let's See The Issues With Your Rewrite Rule..

1. The first parameter passed to `add_rewrite_rule()` (which is the regular expression pattern) should not start with `home_url()` or any functions which outputs the website URL. So this is wrong:

   ```
   home_url() . '/car/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?'
   ```

   because the generated regular expression (RegEx) pattern would be:

   ```
   http://example.com/car/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?
   ```

   which will **never be matched**, because the request (see [`WP::$request`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L53)) never starts with the website URL. And it doesn't even start with `/`.
2. Is the `&model=$matches[1]` part a typo?

   ```
   index.php?taxonomy=car&term=$matches[1]&model=$matches[1]&trim=$matches[2]
   ```

### Now The Fixes

1. The `home_url() . '/car/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?'` should be (no trailing `/` at the start):

   ```
   '^car/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?'
   ```
2. The `index.php?taxonomy=car&term=$matches[1]&model=$matches[1]&trim=$matches[2]` should *probably* be without the `&model=$matches[1]`:

   ```
   index.php?taxonomy=car&term=$matches[1]&trim=$matches[2]
   ```

   However, even *with* that `&model=$matches[1]`, the rule actually worked *in my case*.
3. And not sure if you've already added this somewhere in your code, but I'd add it so that I could get the value of the "trim" parameter in the URL:

   ```
   add_rewrite_tag( '%trim%', '([^/]+)' );
   ```

   You'd add that before/after the `add_rewrite_rule()` line, and to get the "trim" value, you could use `get_query_var( 'trim' )`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the super clear answer. It's working now that I've fixed the regex and added the rewrite tag. As for the part that you thought was a typo, you're right, it was accidentally left over from earlier. Thanks again you are a life saver

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad I could help. :)